# Implementing enums with generic outputs with type decided in implementation

Tags: generics, rust, enums, pattern-matching

I have this problem of wanting to create one struct with several fields, where one is an enum deciding the how to handle many operations. Specifically, the enum decides what `input` and `output` types an important function has. I do not want the main structure to include. an initialized structure of the`input`/`output` since they tend to change a lot and the values are not interesting for the main struct.

Given the setup:

```rs
struct Model<I,O> {
    name: String,
    model_type: ModelType
    _data_format: PhantomData::<(I,O)>
    //... many other fields
}

enum ModelType{
    Onnx,
    DecisiomTree,
}

impl ModelType{
   pub fn get_model<I,O>(self) -> Model<I,O>{
      match self {
         Self::Onnx => {
            Model<I,O> {
               name: "onnx".into(),
               model_type: Self::Onnx,
               PhantomData::<(OnnxInput,OnnxOutput)> //  <--- Cant do it like this, what should be done here?? without initializing the given structures.
            }
         },
         //.. other models
     }
   }
}

struct OnnxInput {
    matrix: Vec<Vec<f64>>
}

struct DtInput {
    color: f32,
    size: f32,
    //... more... 
}

impl<I,O> Model<I,O> {
    pub fn score(&self, input: I) -> O{
        
        self.model_type.score::<I>(input)
    }
    
}

impl ModelType{
    pub fn score<I>(&self, input: I) -> O
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is achievable with unit structs implementing a trait, instead of a `ModelType` enum, like this:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait ModelScore {
    type Input;
    type Output;
    
    fn score(i: Self::Input) -> Self::Output;
}

struct Model<T: ModelScore> {
    marker: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T: ModelScore> Model<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
    
    fn score(&self, i: T::Input) -> T::Output {
        T::score(i)
    }
}


struct Onnx;

struct OnnxInput;

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
struct OnnxOutput;

struct DecisionTree;

struct DecisionTreeInput;

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
struct DecisionTreeOutput;

impl ModelScore for Onnx {
    type Input = OnnxInput;
    type Output = OnnxOutput;
    
    fn score(_: Self::Input) -> Self::Output {
        OnnxOutput
    }
}

impl ModelScore for DecisionTree {
    type Input = DecisionTreeInput;
    type Output = DecisionTreeOutput;
    
    fn score(_: Self::Input) -> Self::Output {
        DecisionTreeOutput
    }
}

fn main() {
    let m1: Model<Onnx> = Model::new();
    let m2: Model<DecisionTree> = Model::new();
    
    assert_eq!(m1.score(OnnxInput), OnnxOutput);
    assert_eq!(m2.score(DecisionTreeInput), DecisionTreeOutput);
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0cfc459d6112d2c40a7d1c727dd3c2fc)

Instead of `ModelType` we now have a trait `ModelScore` with associated types `Input` and `Output`. The variants of `ModelType` were replaced by the unit structs `Onnx` and `DecisionTree`, which both implement `ModelScore`. That allows us to define our `Model` instances as seen in the `main` function with `let m1: Model<Onnx> = Model::new()`. Your input and output types are known to the compiler but not initialized, as was your requirement.